# jenkins maven setPerCoreThreadCount

Tags: maven, jenkins

- Jenkins ver. 1.538
- With Maven 3.1.0 works just fine
- With Maven 3.2.1 it get the following error
- Jenkins installed Maven 3.2.1 itself (downloaded from Apache and extracted)

What is wrong?

```
Parsing POMs
maven31-agent.jar already up to date
maven31-interceptor.jar already up to date
maven3-interceptor-commons.jar already up to date
[project] $ /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/java-1.7.0/bin/java -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:PermSize=128M -cp /opt/jenkins/maven31-agent.jar:/opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.2.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:\opt\jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\maven-3.2.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /opt/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.2.1 /opt/jenkins/slave.jar /opt/jenkins/maven31-interceptor.jar /opt/jenkins/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 41476
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
...
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:178)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:184)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest.setPerCoreThreadCount(Z)V
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.populateRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:172)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven31Launcher.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:130)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Maven 3.2 introduced some severe changes in how multithreaded building works unter the hood. For now, I would advise sticking with Maven 3.1. Please file a bug report for maven-plugin (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org)

Comment: filed a bug report: [JENKINS-22486](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22486) for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JENKINS-22486](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22486) was fixed with [Maven plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Works when I remove `-T 1C` Maven argument (one thread per core).